# Как сделать запуск функции с помощью addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html5

Мне нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки read выводилось значение инпутов которые есть в этом же блоке div,  с помощью addEventListener.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let contentMenu = document.getElementById('content-menu');
contentMenu.style.display = "none";

let delet = document.getElementById('delete');
//delet.style.display = "none";

let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
  }
});
}

One();
function One () {
  let div  = document.querySelector('.conteiner-form');
  let newDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
    
    for (let j = 1; j < newDiv.length; j++) {
      let clone= div.cloneNode(true);
      newDiv[j].append(clone);
    }
    
}


fanMenu();
function fanMenu() {
let conteinerForm = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

for (let i = 0; i < conteinerForm.length; i++) {
  conteinerForm[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    
    
    let form = this.closest('.conteiner-form');
    let menu = form.querySelector('.content-menu');
    if (menu.style.display === "block") {
      menu.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      menu.style.display = "block";
  }
}); 
}
}

fanRead();
function fanRead() {
let conteinerForm = document.getElementsByClassName('read');

for (let i = 0; i < conteinerForm.length; i++) {
  conteinerForm[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let menu = this.closest('.content-menu');
    let read = menu.querySelector('.read');
      out();
      fan1();
}); 
}}

fanDel();
function fanDel() {
let conteinerForm = document.getElementsByClassName('del');

for (let i = 0; i < conteinerForm.length; i++) {
  conteinerForm[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = '';
    heaList.length = 0;
    todoList.length = 0; 
}); 
}
}



function fan1 () {
  let text = document.querySelector('.text');
  let input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  if (input !== '' && text !== '')  {
    
    let temp = {}
    temp.todo = text.value;
    temp.check = false;
    let i = todoList.length;
    todoList[i] = temp;
   
    //result.innerHTML = temp.todo;      
    out();
  }else{alert('Error!')};
 }
 function out() {
  let input = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  let result = document.querySelector('.out');
  let name = {};
  name.todo = input;
  name.check = false;
  let j = heaList.length;
  heaList[j] = name;

  let res1 = '';

  for (let key in todoList) {
    res1 += heaList[key].todo + '<br>';
    res1 += todoList[key].todo + '<br>';
  }
  result.innerHTML = '<span>' + res1  + '</span><br>';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div-block">
      <div id="delete">
    <div id="conteiner-form" class="conteiner-form">
        <button class="menu">+</button>  
        <div id="content-menu" class="content-menu">
            <div id="content-menu1" class="content-menu1">
                <input type="text" class="input"><br>
                <textarea class="text"></textarea>
                <button class="read">Вывести</button>
                <button class="del">Очистить список задач</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<button class="accordion">Понедельник</button>
<div class="panel">
    <div id="conteiner-form" class="conteiner-form">
        <button class="menu">+</button>  
        <div id="content-menu" class="content-menu">
            <div id="content-menu1" class="content-menu1">
                <input type="text" class="input"><br>
                <textarea class="text"></textarea>
                <button class="read">Вывести</button>
                <button class="del">Очистить список задач</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3 class="out"></h3>
    </div>
            
    </div>



<button class="accordion">Вторник</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>

<button class="accordion">Среда</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
<button class="accordion">Четверг</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
<button class="accordion">Пятница</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
<button class="accordion">Суббота</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
<button class="accordion">Воскресенье</button>
<div class="panel">
  
</div>
</div> 
          
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="listScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код https://codepen.io/stalk000/pen/ZEOwPpW?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

```js
const writeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')] // получаем все кнопки

for (let i = 0; i < writeBtns.length; i++) {
  writeBtns[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const closestInput = e.target.closest('div').children[0] // ищем ближайший input, из которого будем брать значение
    const closestTextArea = e.target.closest('.wrapper').children[2] // ищем ближайшую textarea, в которую будем помещать значение
    const data = closestInput.value
    closestTextArea.value += data + '\n'
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 250px;">
  <div style="width: calc(100% + 6px); display: flex;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите данные" style="margin-right: 5px; width: 70%">
    <button style="width: 30%">Записать</button>  
  </div>
  <br>
  <textarea style="width: 100%; resize: none; height: 100px; margin: 0;"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="wrapper" style="width: 250px;">
  <div style="width: calc(100% + 6px); display: flex;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите данные" style="margin-right: 5px; width: 70%">
    <button style="width: 30%">Записать</button>  
  </div>
  <br>
  <textarea style="width: 100%; resize: none; height: 100px; margin: 0;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно добавлять в <p></p>?

Comment: можно, если всегда в новый нужно, то создавайте новый `p`, добавляйте в него текст, а затем вставляйте этот `p` куда вам нужно

Comment: если можно только в старый, например, я ввел сразу 123 и вывел в p, а после 456 и вывел в тот же p(p у меня динамически создан) и код как это если не трудно или источник от куда можно взять